# phpmyadmin auth protocol for encryption

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin our main user usually "root" its stored on a DataBase called "mysql" under the "users" table.

My question is, the password under a user, in which format is encrypted? md5? sha1? base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really related to phpMyAdmin ; it depends on the MySQL server itself -- phpMyAdmin being only the tool you're using to interrogate MySQL.

Anyway, this section of MySQL's manual should help you : [**Password Hashing in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html) : *(quoting)* :

> what is stored in the `Password`
>   column of the `user` table is not the
>   plaintext version of the password, but
>   a hash value computed from it.
>   
> Password hash values are computed
>   by the [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function.